# C# Web API connect to MarkLogic API - How to pass credentials

Tags: c#, curl, asp.net-web-api, marklogic

**Technical Stack**

- MarkLogic 9.0.8.2
- Asp.Net core 2.0 & above

I was going thru [ML Rest API](https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/rest) where all examples are given with curl.

Based on this guide, i have created user with rest-read role. Added below in my c# code

```
private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user:password");

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
```

I am not getting any response on this request.

Any reference(s) links will be very helpful.

BTW, I also tried with curl command on server, i am getting "401 Unauthorized" error

curl --anyauth --user user:password  'localhost:8011/v1/search?q=Bollywood'

Is this the right way to pass credentials to ML Rest API or calling curl command?

Comment: Are you missing some code?  I see that you have created the HttpClient and set the headers, but I don't see an actual call to an API.

Comment: Thanks Michael for reply, Sorry for confusion, actually i have written API call, it was just that i missed it to mention here. But it throws 401 Unauthorised error

Comment: I was able to use Digest Authentication and it worked well with admin credentials but not with res-reader, is there any other permissions need to be provided to end user ??
private static HttpClientHandler _handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential
    {
        UserName = "user",
        Password = "password"
    }
};
httpClient = new HttpClient(_handler);